# Modify two tables (insert or update) based on existance of a row in the first table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, transactions, locking

I have a simple thing to do but somehow can't figure out how to do it.
I have to modify **two** tables (insert or update) based on existance of a row in the first table.
There is a possibility that some other process will insert the row with id = 1
between getting the flag value and "if" statement that examines its value.
The catch is - I have to change TWO tables based on the flag value.
Question: How can I ensure the atomicity of this operation?
I could lock both tables by "select with TABLOCKX", modify them and release the lock by committing the transaction but ... won't it be overkill?

```
  declare @flag int = 0
  begin tran
      select @flag = id from table1 where id = 1

      if @flag = 0 
      begin
        insert table1(id, ...) values(1, ...)
        insert table2(id, ...) values(1, ...)
      end
      else
      begin
        update table1 set colX = ... where id = 1
        update table2 set colX = ... where id = 1
      end
  commit tran
```

Comment: I don't think a `TABLOCKX` would be overkill but if you would like to touch only over the row with id = 1 it could be a good idea to `XLOCK` only over this specific row and keep it until you end the transaction.

Comment: @Delta32000 Thanks. But if there is no row with Id=1 there is nothing to put row lock on. Nothing won't prevent insertion of the similar row into the tables while my process is evaluating the flag value.

Comment: I don't know your logical case behind this. If your column [id] is either `PRIMARY KEY` or `UNIQUE` you can put a Lock on that row. If not, in my opinion you won't have other choice than Lock the table with a `TABLOCKX`. I understand that you are in the second option.
Each time I want to ensure the Atomicity of a transaction over a table I go for a table lock X.
If someone has a better option I would have to change a lot of my apps LMAO

Comment: @Delta32000, thanks :). If there will be no other relevant answers we will set your comment as the answer to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sumarize our conversation and generalize to other's case :

If your column `[id]` is either `PRIMARY KEY` or `UNIQUE` you can put a Lock on that row. No other process will be able to change the value of `[id]`

If not, in my opinion you won't have other choice than Lock the table with a `TABLOCKX`. It will prevent any other process to `UPDATE`,`DELETE` or `INSERT` a row.
With that lock, it could possibly allow an other process to `SELECT` over the table depending on your isolation level.

If your database is in `read_committed_snapshot`, the other process would read the "old" value of the same `[id]`.

To check your isolation level you can run

```
SELECT name, is_read_committed_snapshot_on FROM sys.databases
```